# Kafka consumer timeout or number of messages to be downloaded

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I read messages from kafka, but I have problem. Is there a parameter to force the download of messages to end e.g. after an hour? e.g. to start a timeout after an hour or to abort the process.

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server qa-kafka-prod-worker01:9080 --topic test.test.topic1 --from-beginning --consumer-property group.id=READ_DATA> C:\Kafka\topic1_%DATE%.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI tools have no such parameters for time. You'd need to write code to implement that logic

If you only want X messages, then `--max-messages X`, although it still will hang until those messages have arrived

If you want to dump messages into a timed window, then Kafka Connect HDFS sink can write to local filesystem using `file://` URI